# for typescript, how to define an interface inside a class

Tags: typescript, class, interface

in typescript,the normal codes present like this

```
interface Animal {
    dateOfBirth: any;
}

class AnimalHouse {
    greeting(pa:Animal){
        console.log(pa.dateOfBirth);
    }
}
```

I have not found out any explicit usage about this,
is there anyway to put interface declaration inside the class

Comment: Have you tried doing it? Did you run into an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the type inline in the argument list - this'll make the code shorter and easily encapsulated, but you'll lose the `Animal` name, which can be a disadvantage.

```
class AnimalHouse {
    greeting(pa: { dateOfBirth: any }){
        console.log(pa.dateOfBirth);
    }
}
```

You can also use an IIFE to create types scoped only for a particular class.

```
const AnimalHouse = (() => {
    type Animal = {
        dateOfBirth: any;
    }
    return class AnimalHouse {
        greeting(pa: Animal) {
            console.log(pa.dateOfBirth);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Your second block worked well for me. I wish TS had a native solution, and didn't require "trickery" like this. Thank you, nonetheless.